# Python is not recognized only from cmd/bat file with miniconda install

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda, miniconda

If launched directly from the command line python is recognized:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\%USER%>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda
```

and

```
C:\Users\%USER%>python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:00) [MSC
v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path
<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\Lib\ntpath.pyc'>
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Minico
nda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\lib\\l
ib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda', 'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Minicond
a\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>
```

I have a cmd file located in:

```
C:\finished projects\run_aum_insertion.bat
```

Which contains:

```
python C:\Users\%USER$\PycharmProjects\upload_acct_value\Main.py
```

Yet when I run it I get the following error:

```
C:\finished projects>python C:\Users\%USER%\PycharmProjects\upload_acct_va
lue\Main.py
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\finished projects>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Where pause was manually added to view the error.

And my `PATH` variable is the following:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda;C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\Scripts;
```

This is quite strange to me as cmd/bat should just be an automation of whatever I can do manually in command line directly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried ipython?

Comment: @eryksun .py gets sent to notepad++, which makes sense based on prior configuration.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque installing ipy now.

Comment: @eryksun if it fixes it I am not married to having .py sent to np++. Python's installation is already in the path, that is the weird part.

Comment: @eryksun I assigned `.py` to be opened by `C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\python.exe` 
`ImportError: No module named site`

Comment: Is the `PATH` you show referring to the user environment variable in the control panel editor?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque ipython works.

Comment: Have you tried to type ipython i/o python at the command line?

Comment: When you run Python at the command prompt, what's the value of `sys.executable`?

Comment: @eryksun `>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\Miniconda\\python.exe'`

Comment: In your .bat file add the following as the first line `path & pause`. When you run it, is the directory that has python.exe in the list?

Comment: @eryksun i think we have found the culprit!

Comment: I'm concerned that it can't find the `site` module. How do you normally start the command prompt? Does Anaconda come with a launcher, shortcut, or batch file that sets things up? Is it defining a custom `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`? Run `set python & pause` to see all environment variables that start with "python".

Comment: I launch with windows+R. I downloaded conda, not anaconda, so no UI. I use pycharm as a UI. When I run `set python` i get: `
C:\Users\jasonmellone>set python
Environment variable python not defined
`

Comment: right now `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` are not set

Comment: How are you running the bat file?

Comment: Change your bat file to: `"C:\Users\{you}\Miniconda\python.exe" "C:\Users\{you}\PycharmProjects\upload_acct_value\Main.py"`